# Aws Cognito verification sends code instead of link despite the pool's verification message option being set to 'link'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So far, I can only manage to send an email with a verification code, not a link, no matter if I have 'Verification type' 'Code' or 'Link' selected, a verification code is sent either way. I have a cognito domain set up as well for my user pool. Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - Lambda was sending an auth link instead of an auth code bc I unknowingly added a lambda custom message function when choosing `Walkthrough all the auth configurations` when asked ? `What do you want to do?` during the `amplify add auth' cli flow.

[This AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html) says "You can edit static custom messages in the Message customizations tab of the original Amazon Cognito console." But I had the same issue as you - no backend changes after settings were changed in Amplify Studio nor the Cognito console.

I finally found a promising solution in this [aws-amplify / amplify-cli github issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2458)

Here is are the steps I had to take:

```
app % amplify update auth
Please note that certain attributes may not be overwritten if you choose to use defaults settings.

You have configured resources that might depend on this Cognito resource.  Updating this Cognito resource could have unintended side effects.

Using service: Cognito, provided by: awscloudformation
 What do you want to do? Walkthrough all the auth configurations
 Select the authentication/authorization services that you want to use: User Sig
n-Up, Sign-In, connected with AWS IAM controls (Enables per-user Storage feature
s for images or other content, Analytics, and more)
 Allow unauthenticated logins? (Provides scoped down permissions that you can co
ntrol via AWS IAM) Yes
 Do you want to enable 3rd party authentication providers in your identity pool?
 Yes
 Select the third party identity providers you want to configure for your identi
ty pool: Google
  
 You've opted to allow users to authenticate via Google.  If you haven't already
, you'll need to go to https://developers.google.com/identity and create an App 
ID. 
 
 Enter your Google Web Client ID for your identity pool
 <Client ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com
 Do you want to add User Pool Groups? No
 Do you want to add an admin queries API? No
 Multifactor authentication (MFA) user login options: OFF
 Email based user registration/forgot password: Enabled (Requires per-user email
 entry at registration)
 Specify an email verification subject: Your verification code
 Specify an email verification message: Your verification code is {####}
 Do you want to override the default password policy for this User Pool? No
 Specify the app's refresh token expiration period (in days): 30
 Do you want to specify the user attributes this app can read and write? No
 Do you want to enable any of the following capabilities? 
 Do you want to use an OAuth flow? Yes
 What domain name prefix do you want to use? claimsexaminer
 Which redirect signin URIs do you want to edit? http://localhost:3000/, https:/
/<amplify id>_<env-name>.amplifyapp.com/
? Update http://localhost:3000/ http://localhost:3000/
? Update https://<amplify id>_<env-name>.amplifyapp.com/ https://<amplify id>_<env-name>.amplifyapp.com/
 Do you want to add redirect signin URIs? Yes
 Enter your new redirect signin URI: http://localhost:3000/
? Do you want to add another redirect signin URI Yes
 Enter your new redirect signin URI: https://<amplify id>_<env-name>.amplifyapp.c
om/
? Do you want to add another redirect signin URI No
 Which redirect signout URIs do you want to edit? 
 Do you want to add redirect signout URIs? Yes
 Enter your new redirect signout URI: http://localhost:3000/
? Do you want to add another redirect signout URI Yes
 Enter your new redirect signout URI: https://<amplify id>_<env-name>.amplifyapp.
com/
? Do you want to add another redirect signout URI No
 Select the OAuth flows enabled for this project. Authorization code grant
 Select the OAuth scopes enabled for this project. Phone, Email, OpenID, Profile
, aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
 Select the identity providers you want to configure for your user pool: Google
  
 You've opted to allow users to authenticate via Google.  If you haven't already
, you'll need to go to https://developers.google.com/identity and create an App 
ID. 
 
 Enter your Google Web Client ID for your OAuth flow:  <Client ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com
 Enter your Google Web Client Secret for your OAuth flow:  <Client Secret>
? Do you want to configure Lambda Triggers for Cognito? Yes
? Which triggers do you want to enable for Cognito 
Removing resource <amplify-automated-prefix>CustomMessage...
✅ Successfully removed resource
✅ Successfully updated auth resource <amplify-automated-app_name> locally

✅ Some next steps:
"amplify push" will build all your local backend resources and provision it in the cloud
"amplify publish" will build all your local backend and frontend resources (if you have hosting category added) and provision it in the cloud

✅ Successfully updated resource update locally

✅ Some next steps:
"amplify push" will build all your local backend resources and provision it in the cloud
"amplify publish" will build all your local backend and frontend resources (if you have hosting category added) and provision it in the cloud

app % amplify push
⠹ Fetching updates to backend environment: staging from the cloud.⠋ Building res✔ Successfully pulled backend environment staging from the cloud.

    Current Environment: staging
    
┌──────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Category │ Resource name                       │ Operation │ Provider plugin   │
├──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Auth     │ <app_name>                          │ Update    │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Function │ <amplify-prefix>CustomMessage       │ Delete    │ awscloudformation │
└──────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────┘
✔ Are you sure you want to continue? (Y/n) · yes
```

Once amplify push was completed I deleted the user in Amplify Studio -> User Management console. Then I signed in again with the email/username and HAZAH! Lambda sent out a verification code.